# Can't update React state with text input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

What I'm trying to do is I want to get the list of employees from API, save them in state and do a "live" search by employee name.

Where I struggle is that I can't update my state with filtered array. When I start typing in search field, employees filters, but once I delete some of the letters, nothing changes.

If I .map() not state, but variable that contains filtered array, everything works just fine. This is somehow related to state and state update.

Here is my code:

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 1280px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    :hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
  }
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    padding: 5px;
  }
`;
const TopHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  input {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
`;

function App() {
  const [employees, updateEmployees] = useState([]);

  if (employees == 0) {
    document.title = "Loading...";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        updateEmployees(result.data);
        document.title = `Total: ${result.data.length} `;
      });
  }, []);

  const [searchValue, updateSearch] = useState("");

  const filteredEmpl = employees.filter(empl => {
    return empl.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  });

  const handleSearch = e => {
    updateSearch(e.target.value);
    updateEmployees(filteredEmpl);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <TopHeader>
        <div>
          Total employees: <strong>{employees.length}</strong> Filtered
          employees: <strong>{filteredEmpl.length}</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleSearch}
            value={searchValue}
            placeholder="search"
          />
        </div>
      </TopHeader>

      <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Employee name</th>
            <th>Employee salary</th>
            <th>Employee age</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {employees.map(employee => (
            <tr key={employee.id}>
              <td>{employee.id}</td>
              <td>{employee.employee_name}</td>
              <td>{employee.employee_salary}</td>
              <td>{employee.employee_age}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas what's missing?

Comment: Can you put `const [searchValue, updateSearch] = useState("");` on the first lines along with other `useState` and tell if it works? Also can you make a [sandbox](https://react.new/) so it helps us debugging easier?

Comment: `updateEmployees(filteredEmpl);` - If you remove your search query, where is it supposed to find the original set of employees? You might want to keep a separate state for filtered employees, or a `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the search term is stale here

```js
const handleSearch = e => {
    updateSearch(e.target.value);
    updateEmployees(filteredEmpl);
  };
```

while calling `updateEmployees`. And you're also replacing the result you got from the api call each time you do a search. There's no need setting the search term to state, do this instead:

```js
  const [searchResult, updateSearch] = useState([]);

  const filterEmpl = useCallback((searchTerm) => {
    return employees.filter(({employee_name}) => {
      return employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    })
  }, [employees]);

  const handleSearch = useCallback(({target}) => {
    const filteredEmpl = filterEmpl(target.value)
    updateSearch(filteredEmpl);
  }, [filterEmpl]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the filtered employees into a state variable. You just need to compute it from the original employees each time the `searchValue` or the `employees` are updated (by using `useMemo`).

By the way, it would be preferable to manage the title into its own effect like above.

```
const [employees, updateEmployees] = useState([]);
const [searchValue, updateSearch] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => updateEmployees(result.data));
}, []);

useEffect(() {
  document.title = !employees.length ? "Loading..." : `Total: ${employees.length} `
}, [employees]);

const filteredEmpl = useMemo(() => {
   if (!searchValue) return employees;

   return employees.filter(empl => 
       empl.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
   );
}, [employees, searchValue]);

const handleSearch = e => updateSearch(e.target.value);
```

If you want to sort the array of employees, you can do like this

```
const filteredEmpl = useMemo(() => {
   const sortFn = (empl1, empl2) => {...};
   const filterFn = empl => 
     empl.employee_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());

   if (!searchValue) {
     return [...employees].sort(sortFn);
   } else {
     return employees.filter(filterFn).sort(sortFn);
   }
}, [employees, searchValue]);
```

If the sort criteria can be updated by the user (with an input), then you need to store the sort criteria into a new state variable.

Comment: What about if I want to sort this array by name letters and later sort by salary? I need to store filtered array somewhere. Don't I?

Comment: you just need to call the `sort` method after filtering the employees (I will update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little adjustment to your code by changing a couple of variable names and added a filter function. I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any further assistance with this issue. Cheers!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./App.css";

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 1280px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    :hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
  }
  td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    padding: 5px;
  }
`;

const TopHeader = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  input {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
`;

const Loading = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  text-align: 'center';
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
`;

const App = () => {
    const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]); // Change variable name from updateEmployees to setEmployees
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(""); // changed variable name from updateSearch to setSearchValue
    const [employeesTotal, setEmployeesTotal] = useState(0); // Add a new state to handle intial employees total

    // Renamed employees variable to employeesTotal
    if (employeesTotal) {
        document.title = "Loading...";
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                setEmployees(result.data);
                setEmployeesLength(result.data.length);
                document.title = `Total: ${result.data.length} `; // Why though?
            });
    }, []);

    const handleSearch = e => {
        setSearchValue(e.target.value);
    };

    const filterDocument = doc => {
        const employeeName = doc.employee_name.toLowerCase() || '';
        return employeeName.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
    };

    // Check if employees array contains data, if it does, display content, otherwise show loading
    return (
            employeesTotal ? (
                <Container>
                    <TopHeader>
                        <div>
                            Total employees: <strong>{employeesTotal}</strong> Filtered employees: <strong>{employees.length}</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                onChange={handleSearch}
                                value={searchValue}
                                placeholder="search"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </TopHeader>

                    <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Employee name</th>
                                <th>Employee salary</th>
                                <th>Employee age</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {/** Add filterDocument to filter function on employee array before calling its map funtion */}
                            {employees.filter(filterDocument).map(employee => (
                                <tr key={employee.id}>
                                    <td>{employee.id}</td>
                                    <td>{employee.employee_name}</td>
                                    <td>{employee.employee_salary}</td>
                                    <td>{employee.employee_age}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </Container>
            ) : (
                    <Loading>Loading...</Loading>
                )
    );
}

export default App;
```